# Retain externally copied text when yanking

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I've got `clipboard=unnamed` which means that when I copy from somewhere outside Vim, I can just "put" it into Vim without any additional thought. Most is the time this is perfectly adequate.

Except if I want to delete some text before pasting, in which case the deleted text occupies the `*` register and my old copy is nowhere to be found!

This operation is catered for within Vim because any yank also populates the 0 register, but copies from outside Vim obviously don't do this.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use `:set clipboard+=unnamed`, but rather prefer to explicitly tell Vim when to use the clipboard and when not.

For your case, you can use `P` while in visual mode, [which does not alter the unnamed register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_P), so I would map to something like this:

```
xnoremap <leader>P "+P
```

And then you can select what you want to be overridden and use `<leader>P` to paste from the clipboard and it would also not change your unnamed register.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something like the following would be as good a start as any:

```
function! Foo()
    let clip = getreg('*')
    normal "*p
    call setreg('*', clip)
endfunction
xnoremap <key> <Cmd>call Foo()<CR>
```

where we…

1. define a visual mode mapping on `<key>`,
2. back-up the current content of register `*`,
3. put the content of register `*`, which replaces its content with the previously selected text,
4. restore register `*` from our backup.

Now, pressing `<key>` should replace the visually selected text with what you just copied outside of Vim.

Note that this quick and dirty solution *adds* a new mapping, which might not suit your needs ("without any additional thought"). A broader solution that could be mapped to `p` without losing functionality might be achievable but it will certainly be a bit more involved.

It could also be expanded to update register `0` for maximum "canonicalness".